# How to add multiple node in xml using java

Tags: java, xml, batch-file, xml-parsing

I want to create an xml file like this:

```
  <Record Number="001">
    <RefNum></RefNum>
    <TrackRef></TrackRef>
  <Record>
</Batch>
```

How can i create element Record Number with spaces in between and how to give its value as "001"?

Comment: Need to create above file using java only

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/

Comment: You cannot create an XML Element with the name "Record Number" . You can create an XML Element with the name "Record" that has an attribute named "Number" and value of "001"

Comment: Thanks Michael your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DocumentBuilder for creating this xml.

Please see some sample code below:

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory =
 DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 DocumentBuilder dBuilder = 
    dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
 Document doc = dBuilder.newDocument();
 // root element
 Element rootElement = doc.createElement("");
```

Then output the result in XML file as as shown below :

```
// write the content into xml file
 TransformerFactory transformerFactory =
 TransformerFactory.newInstance();
 Transformer transformer =
 transformerFactory.newTransformer();
 DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
 StreamResult result =
 new StreamResult(new File("C:\\test.xml"));
 transformer.transform(source, result);
```